# Remove quotes between letters

Tags: regex, string, go, quotes

In golang, how can I remove quotes between two letters, like that:

```
import (
    "testing"
)

func TestRemoveQuotes(t *testing.T) {
    var a = "bus\"zipcode"
    var mockResult = "bus zipcode"
    a = RemoveQuotes(a)

    if a != mockResult {
        t.Error("Error or TestRemoveQuotes: ", a)
    }
}
```

Function:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func RemoveQuotes(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "\"", "", -1) //here I removed all quotes. I'd like to remove only quotes between letters

    fmt.Println(s)

    return s
}
```

For example:

> "bus"zipcode" = "bus zipcode"

Comment: The problem is quotes are paired and being between letters has nothing to do with it unless letters are a delimiter for quotes. Even that is moot since in `aadsfsdf""""asdf`, nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a simple `\b"\b` regex that matches a double quote only when preceded *and* followed with word boundaries:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var a = "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"tes\"t3\""
    fmt.Println(RemoveQuotes(a))
}

func RemoveQuotes(s string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b"\b`)
    return re.ReplaceAllString(s, "")
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/3WS3Bgxr-E) printing `"test1","test2","test3"`.

Also, see the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjJPLy/1).

Answer (score 0):

In your example you define a string variable so the outer quotes are not part of the actual string. If you would do `fmt.Println("bus\"zipcode")` the output on the screen would be `bus"zipcode`. If your goal is to replace quotes in a string with a space then you need to replace the quote not with an empty string as you do, but rather with a space - `s = strings.Replace(s, "\"", " ", -1)`. Though if you want to remove the quotes entirely you can do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func RemoveQuotes(s string) string {
    result := ""
    arr := strings.Split(s, ",")
    for i:=0;i<len(arr);i++ {
       sub := strings.Replace(arr[i], "\"", "", -1)
       result = fmt.Sprintf("%s,\"%s\"", result, sub)
    }

    return result[1:]
}

func main() {
    a:= "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"tes\"t3\""
    fmt.Println(RemoveQuotes(a))
}
```

Note however that this is not very efficient, but I assume it's more about learning how to do it in this case.

Comment: var a was a bad example. My var a = "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"tes\"t3\"". I want to only quote insite test3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you need when you commented `I want to only quote inside test3`.

This code is removing the quotes from the inside, as you did, but it is adding the quotes with `fmt.Sprintf()`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var a = "\"test1\",\"test2\",\"tes\"t3\""
    fmt.Println(RemoveQuotes(a))
}

func RemoveQuotes(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "\"", "", -1) //here I removed all quotes. I'd like to remove only quotes between letters

    return fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dKB9DwYXZp

Comment: Thanks for answer @Gerep . But your code retorn "test1,test2,test3", I'd like to "test1","test2","test3".